# reset zoom and pan for a flot js graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flot

I am using the following code to initially construct a flot js graph

```
   var plot = $.plot("#container", [{ data: sin},{ data: cos,yaxis: 2}], 
    {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            backgroundColor: { colors: ["#D1D1D1", "#7A7A7A"] }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d-%b"
        },
        yaxis: { position: "left",min: 0},
        y2axis: { position: "right",min: 0,alignTicksWithAxis: 1},  
        zoom: {
            interactive: true
        },
        pan: {
            interactive: true
        }
    });
```

This allows me to zoom in/out as well as move around the graph. I've got an ajax call to update the axis and data on the graph which looks like below:

```
   success: function(data){
                var get = getDailyDataTEST(data, standard);

                DaysGraphSRC.setData([{ data: get.gr1}, { data: get.gr2,yaxis: 2}]);
                DaysGraphSRC.getOptions().xaxes[0].ticks = get.xaxis;
                DaysGraphSRC.setupGrid();
                DaysGraphSRC.draw();
            }
```

Now my problem is that the zoom and pan don't get updated when new data is loaded. For example, If the user has zoomed in or moved somewhere on the graph and the ajax call updates the data the zoom stays on the same level. Any ideas on how to reset zoom and pan so that they fit the new data which is loaded?

Comment: Have a look at this other question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613874/flot-reset-zoom You'll probably find your answer.

Comment: My problem is that if I redraw the graph like on the example $.plot(container, data, oldOptions) I lose the zoom an pan options of my new graph. How to resolve that then?